# Hadoop job use only 255 cores but I have 784 core cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, emr, amazon-emr

Hi I have 784 core EMR cluster
Im running only one hadoop job but Hadoop job use only 255 cores but I have 784 core cluster can somebody help me how to tune up the cluster to use at least 600 cores

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Some background:**
You defined in Yarn the "Maximum Container Size (VCores)" value - the maximum vcores that could be allocate to the single container. This number obviously is less then the total number of available vcores. When you run a job, the yarn calculate the necessary number of containers and vcores.
Example: Total vcores: 100. Maximum Vcores per container: 10. Job used 3 containers with maximum vcores allocation - 30 vcores in use.

**Answer to your question:** Check for the amount of containers in use by your job and adjust the "Maximum Container Size (VCores)" value.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to request the amount of vcore's that you need for a mapper /reducer container of your job , or bump up yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores: so that every container request will be given a certain minimum vcore's of available vcore's.

ResourceManager on EMR with default **DefaultResourceCalculator** will always allocate 1 vcore per container regardless of what ApplicationMaster asked for containers. So, you'll need to flip it to **DominantResourceCalculator** on *capacity-scheduler.xml* either manually(with a Resource manager restart) or with [EMR configurations API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html) at startup so that it can honor vcore requests from your application.
See similar : [How to set the VCORES in hadoop mapreduce/yarn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522967/how-to-set-the-vcores-in-hadoop-mapreduce-yarn)